# Android Bluetooth enable error

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am developing an android application with bluetooth functionality. But i have got one problem. I am using following code

```
 BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

   if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {

  // Device does not support Bluetooth

    tv.setText("Device is not there");

   setContentView(tv);

   }
   else
   {
       if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new    Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }
   tv.setText("Device is there");
   setContentView(tv);
   }
```

I am getting error at

```
 if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {

 Intent enableBtIntent = new    Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);

 startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }
```

whenever i try to run that code, my application crashes by showing a message box with "Force close" button. Where is the error, i am not figuring it out yet. Kindly help.
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the correct permission in your manifest?
You need to specify that your app will use Bluetooth with:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

in your manifest file.
The manifest file will be named AndroidManifest.xml and visible in your project folder if using Eclipse.

Comment: Yeah, thats what i am making the mistake, Just added the above line in my manifest, and solve the problem. Thanks brother.

Comment: I got the error can't resolve "REQUEST_ENABLE_BT". What is causing this error?